# Why don't questions with close votes always show up in the Close Votes review queue?

Tags: bug

Just now, there was an ID request question that already had 1 close vote. It appeared with a red dot notification under First Posts, but there was no red dot next to Close votes. This isn't the first time this has happened; I will sometimes be looking at a post that has at least one close vote but the review queue won't say that there is anything under Close Votes. It's not consistent, though--the Close Votes review queue often has a red dot notification, so I know it's not just a universal bug. Is this supposed to happen? Does anyone know why it happens?

Comment: This is a know issue on all SE sites. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356697/top-bar-review-needed-red-dot-showing-but-no-red-dot-in-review-queues

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, there are 2 of the possibilities:

1. **The close vote is recent**, and the system (the queue) hasn't picked it up. Review queues are not real-time, and some queues can take more than 10 minutes to pick up the post.
2. **The post has been edited**, and it's kicked out from the queue.

---

For this particular case, the [timeline](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/48415/timeline) explains it all:

- **Posted at 16:32**
- Close vote initiated by Turamarth sometime between 16:32-16:38
- Entered "First Posts" queue at 16:35 and **[reviewed by kuwaly](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/46697) at 16:39**
- Accumulated 3 more close votes *from outside of the queue* sometime between 16:39-22:35
- **Entered "Close Votes" queue at 16:50** and [closed by Logan M](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/close/46698) at 22:35